# Deepcopy all function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, copy

I have the following problem. I have a function which takes 2 lists as arguments. In order not to mutate any of them I would like to use the `copy` module and create a `deepcopy` of both.

Up to now I have only come this far:

```
import copy 

def f(a1, a2):
    a1 = copy.deepcopy(a1)
    a2 = copy.deepcopy(a2)
    # Rest of function code below.
```

I personally do not think that this code looks nice. It would be better to have something like this

```
import copy 

def f(a1, a2):
    newdeepcopy(locals())
    # Rest of function code below. The same code as above.
```

The function `newdeepcopy` should take locals as an argument and redefine the the variables a1 and a2 only in the scope of f. Is this possible?

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Unfortunately there is no better option, but I can deal with that.

Comment: Why do you want to this at all? to me it looks more like an XY problem.

Comment: @Kasramvd: Reuseability of code is, AFAIK, a good practice. I simply don't want to write essentially the same line of code (a1 = copy.deepcopy(a1) ) again and again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using a decorator?

#### Code:

```
def deep_copy_params(to_call):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        return to_call(*copy.deepcopy(args), **copy.deepcopy(kwargs))
    return f
```

#### Test Code:

```
import copy

@deep_copy_params
def test(a, b, c=0):
    print(a, b, c)
    a[1] = 3
    b[2] = 4
    c[3] = 5
    print(a, b, c)

aa = {1: 2}
bb = {2: 3}
cc = {3: 4}

test(aa, bb, cc)
print(aa, bb, cc)
```

#### Results:

```
{1: 2} {2: 3} {3: 4}
{1: 3} {2: 4} {3: 5}
{1: 2} {2: 3} {3: 4}
```